# Syntax error when trying ALTER TABLE

Tags: db2

I'm using Db2 version 11.2.

I just need to align the format of this new table `PORTFOLIO_USER` exact as `PORTFOLIO_USER_OLD`

I have written this code

```
reorg table CA_CAMPAIGN.DM0032_PORTFOLIO_USER

ALTER TABLE CA_CAMPAIGN.DM0032_PORTFOLIO_user ALTER COLUMN ACH_FLG SET DATA TYPE SMALLINT ;
```

it is throwing error

> Lookup Error - DB2 Database Error: ERROR [42601] [IBM][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "ALTER" was found following "".  Expected tokens may include:  "RECLAIM".

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Not enough information.  Are you executing these statements in a script , or via some GUI tool?   If you are using a script, then you must include statement terminator , by default a semicolon at the end of each statement .   Separately what is the existing datatype of column ACH_FLG ?

Comment: You probably want to do a reorg _after_ modifying the table, not before.